# Connect 2 physical machine drops Internet connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have 2 physical machines, with 2 VM on the first physical.
I have been trying to connect 2 physical machines via RJ45 and give internet to the "lan" via NATting RNDIS on one VM (gateway) and routing it to LAN.

[image: Schema]

[image: config]

Now, when I'm trying to access Internet on the Physical 1, the Ethernet takes over RNDIS and then is looping :
Ethernet takes over nat > VM (gateway) > NAT > Ethernet takes over nat...
[image: tracert]
Is there a way to force RNDIS on host Physical 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: What about simply buying a switch ? Show your routes and IPs in use.

Comment: Buying s switch won't solve the problem. I use USB to access Internet, can't switch USB unfortunatly...

Comment: Then unless you decide to use reasonable network management practices (by changing the connectivity type), this question is out of topic and should be moved to superuser.

Comment: This is kind of an esoteric setup... I would probably troubleshoot it by creating a diagram and listing all info (IPs, connections, linkages), then verifying the existing configuration in all systems against that diagram.  It sounds to me like you have incorrect route defined.